# How do you move a leaflet layer?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, translation, openlayers, layer

I have several GeoJSON features (polygons, lines, and points) loaded into Leaflet map. I would like to have some of them be translated and follow the movement of the user's mouse. I don't see anything in the API docs to do this. Is removing and adding the layer the only option? I'd like a solution that is seamless and doesn't flicker too much. If not possible with Leaflet, is Openlayers an alternative for doing this?

Comment: `YourLayer.setLatLng()`

Comment: @StackSlave That seems to be only available for markers and popups and not other layer types.

Comment: I'm working with leaflet myself right now, and can't say I've tried this, but: `polylineInstance.setLatLngs([/* array/s here */).toGeoJSON()` or `circleMarker.setLatLng(/* latLng */).toGeoJSON()`, may work for you?

Comment: Have a look at [Leaflet plugins](https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#markers--renderers). You might be interested in [Leaflet.truesize](https://wbkd.github.io/leaflet-truesize/) one.